# Automating order of citations within parenthesis

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I'm using `chicago` style with `natbib` and am generally happy with the results. What I'm hoping for though is a way to automatically order the appearance of references within each parenthetical citation in some logical way, whether alphabetical or chronological. In other words, if I type `\citep{Smith2009,Smith2001,Jones2010,Jones1999}` I want the results to look like `(Jones,1999,2010;Smith,2001,2009)`.

Other then entering the citations in the order I want in the `.tex` file itself, switching to something like `biblatex` or changing or editing the style I am using, is there a way to get the results I want?

Comment: You aren't giving a lot of room for possible solutions!  It sounds like the only acceptable one would be if `chicago.bst` or `natbib` gave an option for automatic resorting of citations, which should be easy enough to check.

Comment: Good point. I've ruled out the `chicago` package having any options. I'll keep digging through the documentation on `natbib`. Otherwise I will see if there is a style out there which is basically like chicago but does what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the option `sort` for `natbib` in the header of the LaTex file, e.g. `\usepackage[sort]{natbib}`. Items within the same citation will then be listed in the same order that they appear that they appear in the bibliography.