# Automate ordering of citation within parenthesis

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago, multiple-citations

I use the `biblatex-chicago` package and would like to automatically sort citation within parenthesis by order in the bibliography. Basically, I would like to do what `\usepackage[sort]{natbib}`* does, but in biblatex.

> If I type \citep{Smith2009,Smith2001,Jones2010,Jones1999} I want the
>   results to look like (Jones,1999,2010;Smith,2001,2009).

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \RequirePackage[natbib, authordate,backend=biber,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
    ibidtracker=false]{biblatex-chicago}    
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Jones1999,
      author = {Jones, A.},
      year = {1999},
      title = {Title},
      publisher = {Publisher},
    }
 @book{Jones2010,
      author = {Jones, A.},
      year = {2010},
      title = {Title},
      publisher = {Publisher},
    }
 @book{Smith2001,
      author = {Smith, A.},
      year = {2001},
      title = {Title},
      publisher = {Publisher},
    }
 @book{Smith2009,
      author = {Smith, A.},
      year = {2009},
      title = {Title},
      publisher = {Publisher},
    }
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{document}

    \citep{Smith2009,Smith2001,Jones2010,Jones1999}

    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

*Source: [Automating order of citations within parenthesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132261/automating-order-of-citations-within-parenthesis)

Comment: [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: I didn't see a point of adding a MWE because I have exactly the same question as in the link I referred to. Upon re-reading I was indeed unclear. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! The names of the option is sortcites

```
   \RequirePackage[natbib, authordate,backend=biber,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
    ibidtracker=false,sortcites]{biblatex-chicago}
```